# Populate a list in panelgrid containing rows and columns

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I am developing a java web application with spring/hibernate/primefaces/jsf 2.0. I would like to know if I can populate a list in panelgrid containing rows and columns, instead of using datatable? Is there any other alternative? I do not want to use datatable. Please advise.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form>
    <p:panelGrid>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column colspan="1">SN</p:column>
                <p:column colspan="2">List of Rating</p:column>
                <p:column colspan="24">Values</p:column>
            </p:row>

            <p:row>
                <p:column colspan="3" styleClass="ui-widget-header">
                    <p:spacer height="0" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column colspan="8">
                        Rating
                </p:column>

            </p:row>
        </f:facet>

        <p:row>
            <p:column>1</p:column>
            <p:column colspan="2">Innovative Ideas</p:column>
            <p:column colspan="1" style="width:2px;">0</p:column>
            <p:column colspan="1" style="width:2px;">1</p:column>
            <p:column colspan="1" style="width:2px;">2</p:column>
            <p:column colspan="1" style="width:2px;">3</p:column>
            <p:column colspan="1" style="width:2px;">4</p:column>
            <p:column colspan="1" style="width:2px;">5</p:column>
            <p:column colspan="1" style="width:2px;">6</p:column>
            <p:column colspan="1" style="width:2px;">7</p:column>
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column colspan="1">1.1</p:column>
            <p:column colspan="2">New technology</p:column>
            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;" colspan="8">
                <p:selectOneRadio id="rating"
                    styleClass="selectRadio"
                    value="#{ratingComponent.rate.myrating}">
                    <f:selectItems
                        value="#{ratingComponent.ratingList}"
                        var="rate" itemValue="#{rate.code}" itemLabel="" />
                    <p:spacer height="0" width="20" />

                    <p:ajax process="competency_self_rating1"
                        listener="#{ratingComponent.saveRating('1',ratingComponent.rate.myrating,'rating')}" />

                </p:selectOneRadio>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of layout you can always match, e.g. by combining datagrid and panelgrid. Speaking with showcase examples in mind, this would be a basic table rewritten

```
        <p:dataGrid var="car" value="#{tableBean.cars}" columns="1"
            rows="12" paginator="true" id="cars">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" style="width: 100%;">
                <h:outputText  value="#{car.year}"/>
                <h:outputText  value="#{car.model}"/>
                <h:outputText  value="#{car.color}"/>
           </h:panelGrid>
        </p:dataGrid>
```

You might and up in problems though if you need all the dataTable functionalities (multiselection, cell editors etc.). But if layout is your main concerns, you can do it

Comment: I have radio button in column. When i use datagrid, "no record found" is displayed. As such the radio button does not appear.

Comment: feel free to provide some code (simplified but with the reporoducible error, would be preferred). Will help if I have the time

Comment: see edited post. I add my xhtml page. actually it contains panelgrid /rows/columns. After selecting a value from the radiobutton, it saves it in the database. The next time the user open this xhtml page, it should be able to retrieve the value store in database. Can this be done with simple rows n columns? or it should be a datatable/datagrid? my problem with datatable and datagrid, when there is no value in DB, it displays no record found instead of displaying the radio button with blank values.